# Using a post request to grab filtered data from python flask and update current webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, flask

So I have a web page that displays a list of open jobs on the market. There's an advanced search feature on the webpage that filters the results, I use a post request in java script to get these inputs to a python route. I'm confused how to connect these arguments and grab filtered data. So I send the inputs from the front end to a python route. I'm not sure how to then get that filtered data from the backend to the frontend. Do I make an ajax call to that same `app.route`? I can't call `.render_template` due to project structure.

this is what I'm using to get it from the front-end

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#view_csr_search').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var data = {
                role: $('#dropdown_option_1').val(),
                location: $('#location_drop_down').val(),
                mandatory_skills: $('#mandatory_field').val(),
                desired_skills: $('#desired_field').val()
            };

            $.post('/jobs/search',
                    JSON.stringify(data),
                    function (data) {
                        console.log('Posted');
                    }
            )
        });
    });
```

The python `app.route` '/jobs/search/' takes this data, and returns a json object of the data to return. How do I grab this data, when it posts the inputs? Do I just make a normal ajax call to the same app route?

Here's the app route I'm using

```
@app.route('/jobs/search', methods=['POST', 'PUT', 'GET'])
def filter_basic():
    payload = request.json
    location = payload['location']
    role = payload['role']
    q = Job.query # broad query
    q = job_api.role_filter(q, role) # returns filtered query of roles
    q = job_api.location_filter(q, location) # returns filtered query of location
    q = job_api.get_all_jobs(q) #returns list of dictionaries
    return flask.jsonify(q=q)
```

Comment: Does the returned data look correct? If so, just loop over the JSON and create html elements and replace the content of the divider containing the old results with the updated ones.

Comment: Yes, you send the data via ajax to that python function, there you filter the data from the db and then return a JSON string to your callback function in javascript. See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/) an example.

Comment: @reptilicus I am not sure how to return the data. That's my issue. I understand how to jsonify it, but should I call this in the app.route? Whenever I check to see if it's returning it correctly, it says method not allowed

Comment: in the route in flask, the data should come across as request.data or request.json, can grab it there then filter

Comment: @reptilicus would it be request.data["location"] ? this is giving me errors. Isn't it a dictionary?

Comment: updated code to the op. Getting a 400 bad request

Comment: See answer below. 400 error is usually due to badly formed JSON blob, i.e. flask can't serialize it

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, need to set content type to be json so flask can pick it up and serialize it.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "jobs/search",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp)
        //Do something with json blob
    }
});
```

Now in flask:

```
@app.route("/jobs/search")
def search_jobs():
    payload = request.json
    # do something with payload, it will be a dict
```

Comment: I've tried doing payload.location and payload['location'] neither of them work. They both throw errors

Comment: I get errors when returning str(payload) Says it's NoneType so I'm assuming It's not getting it correctly

Comment: try print request.data

Comment: I return str(request.data) and it returns nothing. No error though

Comment: @reptilicus the flask function must accept the `post` method.

Comment: @doru mine does, however it is still nonfunctional

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to have a div for your content that you filter dynamically. When you first hit the route, it will just render all content without any filters. When you change your filter, it will remove that content and replace it with the results of your filter.

Working off your code:

```
$('#job-search-form select[name="filter"]').change(function (ev) {
  // ... get the filters
  var container = $('.data-container');
  $.post('/api/job/search', function (data) {
    container.empty();  // empty the current contents
    data.each(function (job) {
      container.append(job.name);
    });
  });
});
```

This is just a brief example to show concept. I would recommend choosing a front end framework to make the containment of data on the front end more manageable